# How to display number of lines that are blank or contain these characters

Tags: command-line, bash

I have to count the number of lines that contains comma, apostrophe, or is a completely blank line.

I know to count the number of blank lines I would do `egrep -xc '' filename`

But I am not so sure how to do all of it at once, to also get the lines with apostrophe and comma also, as well as blank lines.

Answer (score 5):

It seems you're doing your homework today...

A solution:

```
grep -c "\([',]\|^$\)" filename
```

If by *blank line* you also want to include those that contain only spaces:

```
grep -c "\([',]\|^[[:space:]]*$\)" filename
```

The trick for apostrophes is to use double quotes, otherwise `'''` will be an error. The construct `\( regexp1 \| regexp2 \)` will match all lines that match either `regexp1` or `regexp2`. The regexp `[',]` matches all lines that contain either a quote `'` or a coma `,`.

Here you need to escape the parentheses `()` and the pipe `|` otherwise *grep* tries to find these characters, and don't consider them as regexp constructs. If you don't like escaping these, you can use the `-E` switch (for Extended regexps) or *egrep* directly as:

```
grep -cE "([',]|^$)" filename
```

or

```
egrep -c "([',]|^$)" filename
```

In your OP you mention the `-x` switch. It works to get empty lines... but will not work with your coma/quote requirement. So to match a blank line I'm using `^$` (`^` is an anchor for the beginning of line and `$` is an anchor for the end of line).

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is no difference between solution 1 (without blanks) and solution 2 (with blanks). May I suggest that the second solution read `grep -c "\([',]\|^ *$\)" filename` or `egrep -c "([',]|^ *$)" filename`? Please correct me if this is wrong.

Comment: @PaddyLandau Thanks for spotting the typo! I've fixed it now.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it (and showing me how it should be done). I think that the same applies to the `egrep` examples, doesn't it?

Comment: @PaddyLandau Yes, same applies for `egrep`: `^$` matches really empty line (no blanks), and `^[[:spaces:]]*$` matches empty lines (that may contain spaces, tabs, etc.).